# Microsoft Advertising inside win32 app

Tags: winapi, winjs

Is it somehow possible to use the new Microsoft Advertising JS modules (From Windows 8 Metro) inside traditional win32 applications?

I have win32 application where I would like to implement some Adds with Microsoft Advertising, I don't want to port the application to Metro.